# MS Teams Bot- options to Save data in user instance of teams

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have created a Teams bot application, which needs to save data received from users. I am currently using azure cloud storage for that, but now as the client requested I want to save the data in the user's MS teams instance. What are my possible options?

Comment: Please refer to below doc which explains how to save user and conversation data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Is your issue resolved or are you looking for any help?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately this wont help me acheive my requirement. To elaborate my requirement, My bot gets installed on a team and then i collect some data from the team members and a service process that dat in backgroud to help admin to perform some task and see data in consolidated structure. Now the link you have provided helps in saving the conversation specific to user and cant be used other time.

Comment: @SwapnilChowkekar -  Could you please elaborate on what kind of data you are storing in Azure cloud storage and what data you want to save in User's MS Teams instance?

Comment: I am collecting birthdate and joining date from the team members and storing it in azure storage, but as it's personal data clients don't want it to be saved remotely instead they want to save it in their team's instance.

Comment: Could you please refer this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview) if it helps you in any way.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Prasad-MSFT. I will go through this and see if i can use any of these extensions.